# Here map version upgrade to 3.1

Tags: javascript, heremaps, versionupgrade

I am upgrading javascript here maps to version 3.1. While replacing few old methods with new ones, there is one method which is not working in v3.1. The method is

```
var oldStrip = polygon.getStrip(); //polygon.getStrip() is the old version method
var pntcnt = oldStrip.getPointCount();
```

When I replaced `polygon.getStrip();` with `polygon.getGeometry();` and the further code is as it is -

```
var oldStrip = polygon.getGeometry();
var pntcnt = oldStrip.getPointCount();
```

i get the following error as -
**Uncaught TypeError: oldStrip.getPointCount is not a function**

**Note** - The response of polygon.getStrip() is different than that of polygon.getGeometry()

Any help is appreciated, **TIA**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var oldStrip = polygon.getGeometry();

1. If oldStrip is H.geo.Polygon, you can use its method [getExterior](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.0.0/dev_guide/topics_api/h-geo-polygon.html#h-geo-polygon__getexterior) to obtain the exterior ring of the polygon (H.geo.LineString) and then its getPointCount method which returns the number of points stored in this LineString.

   ```
   oldStrip.getExterior().getPointCount();
   ```

   If oldStrip has interior rings, you need to use its method [getInteriors](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.0.0/dev_guide/topics_api/h-geo-polygon.html#h-geo-polygon__getinteriors) to calculate the number of points for all of them.
2. If oldStrip is H.geo.MultiPolygon, you need to repeat step 1 for each polygon in the collection.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!! @AnatolySukhanov Apology for not responding sooner.